# Javascript. I can't change CSS of the timer

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I have a code of a simple timer. After I press the button, it calls a function (with 2 variables = id of the div where to place the timer after creation, and amount of seconds), that writes timer using innerHTML. I want to change style of the timer outside of HTML in a separate CSS file. But it doesn't work, even if I enclose timer code into div and call it's id in CSS.So so far I can chenge it only inside the function.
Why does it happening, and how can I solve this problem ?

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}



.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
```

```html
<script>
//Timer function
function timer(tag,sec){ 
document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML= "<div id= 'inTime'; style='color: #ffffff; border-radius: 5px;  background-color: #f4511e; padding: 20px; text-align: center;  position: fixed;   width: 200px; '>" + 
(sec / 60 >>0) + 'min ' + sec % 60 + 'sec' + '<br>' + "</div>";



if ((sec / 60 >>0)!=0 || (sec % 60)!=0) {
setTimeout(function() { timer(tag, sec); },1000);
sec -= 1;
}
else {
document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML= "Time is over!";}
}

</script> 

<div id="timerPlace"></div> 
<br><br><br><br>
<!-- Write number of seconds here: onclick="timer('str',...here!...)  -->

<button class="button" onclick="timer('timerPlace',3600)"> <span>Start Test</span> </button>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<!-- Place this div where you whant timer to be. -->
```

Here are version with separate CSS (which isn't working)

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}



.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;

  #inTime {
    color: red;
    font-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script>
//Timer function
function timer(tag,sec){ 
document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML= "<div id= 'inTime';>" + 
(sec / 60 >>0) + 'min ' + sec % 60 + 'sec' + '<br>' + "</div>";



if ((sec / 60 >>0)!=0 || (sec % 60)!=0) {
setTimeout(function() { timer(tag, sec); },1000);
sec -= 1;
}
else {
document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML= "Time is over!";}
}

</script> 
<!-- Place this div where you whant timer to be. -->
<div id="timerPlace"></div> 
<br><br><br><br>

<!-- Write number of seconds here: onclick="timer('str',...here!...)  -->
<button class="button" onclick="timer('timerPlace',3600)"> <span>Start Test</span> </button>
```

Comment: Nothing in the CSS you posted seems to have anything to do with `<div id=inTime>`

Comment: @Pointy yes, this is a working example, with CSS inside HTML. I will post an example with separate CSS in a second.

Comment: You have an error in your CSS. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: the reason your attempt doesn't work is because you are missing a brace (`}`) after your `.button:hover span:after {` block. This will cause the following rule to be ignored.

---

You haven't shown us your attempts to do this with CSS so I couldn't tell you why it didn't work, but this is how you would do it:

```
#inTime {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Example:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
#inTime {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script>
  //Timer function
  function timer(tag, sec) {
    document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "<div id= 'inTime'>" +
      (sec / 60 >> 0) + 'min ' + sec % 60 + 'sec' + '<br>' + "</div>";



    if ((sec / 60 >> 0) != 0 || (sec % 60) != 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        timer(tag, sec);
      }, 1000);
      sec -= 1;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "Time is over!";
    }
  }
</script>

<div id="timerPlace"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- Write number of seconds here: onclick="timer('str',...here!...)  -->

<button class="button" onclick="timer('timerPlace',3600)"> <span>Start Test</span> 
</button>

<!-- Place this div where you whant timer to be. -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change it in the CSS, but it did not work because of the conflict with the original function's style, which is always called (always refreshed).

If you remove the color from the function and set it only in the CSS, you can change it freely to whatever you need.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}



.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

#inTime {
  color:"#ff0000";
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Timer function
function timer(tag,sec){ 
document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML= "<div id= 'inTime'; style='border-radius: 5px;  padding: 20px; text-align: center;  position: fixed;   width: 200px; '>" + 
(sec / 60 >>0) + 'min ' + sec % 60 + 'sec' + '<br>' + "</div>";



if ((sec / 60 >>0)!=0 || (sec % 60)!=0) {
setTimeout(function() { timer(tag, sec); },1000);
sec -= 1;
}
else {
document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML= "Time is over!";}
}

</script> 

<div id="timerPlace"></div> 
<br><br><br><br>
<!-- Write number of seconds here: onclick="timer('str',...here!...)  -->

<button class="button" onclick="timer('timerPlace',3600)"> <span>Start Test</span> </button>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<!-- Place this div where you whant timer to be. -->
```